# writeRaster as rendered image

Tags: r, image, raster

I have a raster stack that I'm trying to export with the Terra::writeRaster function. It exports fine with this method and I can view it in Arc/Q GIS software. But the end goal is to use the raster as a multi-channel image in Unity and this geotiff shows as completely blank. A workaround I've found that preserved the channels is to use QGIS and export as rendered image. I would like to find a way to do all this exporting in R or even export them as PNGs in R.

The current export code

```
raster_stack  <-  stack(speed_raster,  dir_raster)
raster_stack <- brick(raster_stack)

terra::writeRaster(raster_stack, "D:/Wind/RasterStacks/RasterStack.tif", filetype = "GTIFF",overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is all a bit vague. What are the requirements for Unity? I am guessing that you need a standard graphics image, not a GeoTiff. In that case you can use a different driver, such as PNG. You can also use

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
writeRaster(s, "test.png")
```

Or plot on a graphics file device

```
png("test2.png")
plotRGB(s)
dev.off()
```

By the way, `writeRaster` is a generic function that is implemented for SpatRaster and Raster* objects. Since `raster_stack` is a RasterBrick you are actually using the writeRaster function defined in the raster package. This is because the function selected depends on the class of the first argument. Prepending `terra::` as you do in `terra::writeRaster` does not do anything in this case except for causing confusion (`raster::writeRaster` would be OK).

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I've edited the question to minimize confusion with the terra package. I was trying previously to export directly as a PNG using the writeRaster function but I'm still getting the following: "Warning message:
In .getFormat(filename) : extension .png is unknown. Using default format.". Am I missing something?

Comment: That is because you are using a RasterBrick. What I show works with a SpatRaster.